# Header background resizable

Tags: html, css

I have a background image on header but I want it resizable when the browser is small. When I make the browser smaller the image is getting smaller from sides. I want to see the whole image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header{ 
   background: url(img/img.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

You don't really see the whole image all the time but I think this is the best solution as the image will always stay scalable.

[Here](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/background-size.html) you can see the difference between both answers given. The `background-size: cover` and the `background-size:100% auto;` You have to adapt to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use background-size property in CSS

```
{
background-size:100% auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```